# I can't find POST requests to API on Request tab of telescope. but I see GET requests. What can I do to see all request?

Tags: debugging, configuration, laravel-8, laravel-telescope

after installation telescope into laravel 8.

```
"laravel/framework": "^8.40",
"laravel/telescope": "^4.9",
```

visited to /telescope but I don't any see requests hitting to API via POSTMAN/Telegram BOT API

How to check if telescope is watching POST requests?